# REST Api returns Captcha

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express

I'm trying to consume a bitcoin price history rest web service (https://www.coindesk.com/api/) using the URL https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/historical/close.json.

It works fine when I enter the previous URL in my browser, but when I use Node/Express to get the data and then resend it, with the code below it doesn't work, When I send a GET request to m Node/Express server with Postman I get the HTML result at the bottom of this post which looks like a Captcha:

Node/Express code:

```js
const express = require('express');
const request = require('request');

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/bitcoinPrices', function(req, res) {
    request('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/historical/close.json',  function (error, response, body) {
        console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
        console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
        res.send(body);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Response after a GET request to `http://localhost:3000/api/bitcoinPrices`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en-US">
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]>
    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en-US">
        <![endif]-->
        <!--[if IE 8]>
        <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en-US">
            <![endif]-->
            <!--[if gt IE 8]>
            <!-->
            <html class="no-js" lang="en-US">
                <!--
                <![endif]-->
                <head>
                    <title>Attention Required! | Cloudflare</title>
                    <meta name="captcha-bypass" id="captcha-bypass" />
                    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
                    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
                    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />
                    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1" />
                    <link rel="stylesheet" id="cf_styles-css" href="/cdn-cgi/styles/cf.errors.css" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" />
                    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
                    <link rel="stylesheet" id='cf_styles-ie-css' href="/cdn-cgi/styles/cf.errors.ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" />
                    <![endif]-->
                    <style type="text/css">body{margin:0;padding:0}</style>
                    <!--[if lte IE 9]>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="/cdn-cgi/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <![endif]-->
                    <!--[if gte IE 10]>
                    <!-->
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="/cdn-cgi/scripts/zepto.min.js"></script>
                    <!--
                    <![endif]-->
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="/cdn-cgi/scripts/cf.common.js"></script>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <div id="cf-wrapper">
                        <div class="cf-alert cf-alert-error cf-cookie-error" id="cookie-alert" data-translate="enable_cookies">Please enable cookies.</div>
                        <div id="cf-error-details" class="cf-error-details-wrapper">
                            <div class="cf-wrapper cf-header cf-error-overview">
                                <h1 data-translate="challenge_headline">One more step</h1>
                                <h2 class="cf-subheadline">
                                    <span data-translate="complete_sec_check">Please complete the security check to access</span> api.coindesk.com
                                </h2>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.header -->
                            <div class="cf-section cf-highlight cf-captcha-container">
                                <div class="cf-wrapper">
                                    <div class="cf-columns two">
                                        <div class="cf-column">
                                            <div class="cf-highlight-inverse cf-form-stacked">
                                                <form class="challenge-form" id="challenge-form" action="/cdn-cgi/l/chk_captcha" method="get">
                                                    <script type="text/javascript" src="/cdn-cgi/scripts/cf.challenge.js" data-type="normal"  data-ray="3e6fb7629a536938" async data-sitekey="6LfBixYUAAAAABhdHynFUIMA_sa4s-XsJvnjtgB0"></script>
                                                    <div class="g-recaptcha"></div>
                                                    <noscript id="cf-captcha-bookmark" class="cf-captcha-info">
                                                        <div>
                                                            <div style="width: 302px">
                                                                <div>
                                                                    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/fallback?k=6LfBixYUAAAAABhdHynFUIMA_sa4s-XsJvnjtgB0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="width: 302px; height:422px; border-style: none;"></iframe>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div style="width: 300px; border-style: none; bottom: 12px; left: 25px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; right: 25px; background: #f9f9f9; border: 1px solid #c1c1c1; border-radius: 3px;">
                                                                    <textarea id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response" class="g-recaptcha-response" style="width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid #c1c1c1; margin: 10px 25px; padding: 0px; resize: none;"></textarea>
                                                                    <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </noscript>
                                                </form>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="cf-column">
                                            <div class="cf-screenshot-container">
                                                <span class="cf-no-screenshot"></span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- /.columns -->
        
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.captcha-container -->
                            <div class="cf-section cf-wrapper">
                                <div class="cf-columns two">
                                    <div class="cf-column">
                                        <h2 data-translate="why_captcha_headline">Why do I have to complete a CAPTCHA?</h2>
                                        <p data-translate="why_captcha_detail">Completing the CAPTCHA proves you are a human and gives you temporary access to the web property.</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="cf-column">
                                        <h2 data-translate="resolve_captcha_headline">What can I do to prevent this in the future?</h2>
                                        <p data-translate="resolve_captcha_antivirus">If you are on a personal connection, like at home, you can run an anti-virus scan on your device to make sure it is not infected with malware.</p>
                                        <p data-translate="resolve_captcha_network">If you are at an office or shared network, you can ask the network administrator to run a scan across the network looking for misconfigured or infected devices.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.section -->
                            <div class="cf-error-footer cf-wrapper">
                                <p>
                                    <span class="cf-footer-item">Cloudflare Ray ID: 
                                        <strong>3e6fb7629a536938</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="cf-footer-separator">&bull;</span>
                                    <span class="cf-footer-item">
                                        <span data-translate="your_ip">Your IP</span>: 46.193.1.145
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="cf-footer-separator">&bull;</span>
                                    <span class="cf-footer-item">
                                        <span data-translate="performance_security_by">Performance &amp; security by</span>
                                        <a data-orig-proto="https" data-orig-ref="www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing?utm_source=error_footer" id="brand_link" target="_blank">Cloudflare</a>
                                    </span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.error-footer -->


    
                        </div>
                        <!-- /#cf-error-details -->
  
                    </div>
                    <!-- /#cf-wrapper -->
                    <script type="text/javascript">
  window._cf_translation = {};
  
  
</script>
                </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: That's because they use CloudFlare but hasn't set it up properly to work with an API. There's no stable and legitimate way to bypass that. You should contact their support.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get the info using jQuery ajax call and then send it to your express server and process it

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/historical/close.json",
})
.done(function( data ) {
    alert(data)
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/egLqh4ja/